# how to group multiple radio button under radio group

Tags: java, android, android-library, android-radiogroup

i have a simple Activity, what i wanted to do is display 6 radio button in a single radio group

xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >


    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/adbms_radioBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"

            android:text="@string/adbms" />

         <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/we_radioBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:text="@string/we" />

          <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/mp_radioBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:text="@string/mp" />



    </TableRow>

    <TableRow 
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/tcs_radioBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"    
            android:text="@string/tcs" 
            />

            <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/evs_radioBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="56dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/evs" />

            <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/cn_radioBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
            android:text="@string/cn" ></RadioButton>

     </TableRow>

</RadioGroup>
</LinearLayout>
```

but it is not working, means i can select all the radio button, but what i want is only one radio button should be selected, selecting another radio button should deselect the first one
can any one help please?

i have coded this to implement radiogroup like functionality but it is not working as expected, whenever i am select multiple radiobuttons it is getting selected

```
    package com.example.istudy;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AddMenuScreen extends Activity implements OnClickListener, OnCheckedChangeListener{

    private RadioButton adbmsRadioBtn;
    private RadioButton cnRadioBtn;
    private RadioButton tcsRadioBtn;
    private RadioButton evsRadioBtn;
    private RadioButton mpRadioBtn;
    private RadioButton weRadioBtn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.add_activity);
        Button doneBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.doneBtn);
        doneBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
        adbmsRadioBtn = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.adbms_radioBtn);
        weRadioBtn = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.we_radioBtn);
        mpRadioBtn = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.mp_radioBtn);
        evsRadioBtn = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.evs_radioBtn);
        tcsRadioBtn = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.tcs_radioBtn);
        cnRadioBtn = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.cn_radioBtn);








        adbmsRadioBtn.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
        cnRadioBtn.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
        mpRadioBtn.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
        weRadioBtn.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
        evsRadioBtn.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
        tcsRadioBtn.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.doneBtn:
            saveData( );

//          Toast.makeText(AddMenuScreen.this, "done btn clicked..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
    }

    private void saveData() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        EditText chaptersCompletedTxtBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.chaptersCompletedTxtBox);
        int chaptersCompleted = Integer.parseInt( chaptersCompletedTxtBox.getText().toString() );


        if( adbmsRadioBtn.isChecked() ){
            if(  chaptersCompleted > 0 && chaptersCompleted < 9  ){
                insertIntoDB(chaptersCompleted, adbmsRadioBtn.getText().toString());
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(AddMenuScreen.this, "For ADBMS valid range is 1-8", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }else if( weRadioBtn.isChecked() ){

            if(  chaptersCompleted > 0 && chaptersCompleted < 9  ){
                insertIntoDB(chaptersCompleted, weRadioBtn.getText().toString());
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(AddMenuScreen.this, "For WE valid range is 1-8", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }else if( mpRadioBtn.isChecked() ){

            if(  chaptersCompleted > 0 && chaptersCompleted < 8  ){
                insertIntoDB(chaptersCompleted, mpRadioBtn.getText().toString());
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(AddMenuScreen.this, "For MP valid range is 1-7", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }else if( evsRadioBtn.isChecked() ){

            if(  chaptersCompleted > 0 && chaptersCompleted < 9  ){
                insertIntoDB(chaptersCompleted, evsRadioBtn.getText().toString());
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(AddMenuScreen.this, "For EVS valid range is 1-8", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }else if( tcsRadioBtn.isChecked() ){

            if(  chaptersCompleted > 0 && chaptersCompleted < 9  ){
                insertIntoDB(chaptersCompleted, tcsRadioBtn.getText().toString());
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(AddMenuScreen.this, "For TCS valid range is 1-8", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }else if( cnRadioBtn.isChecked() ){

            if(  chaptersCompleted > 0 && chaptersCompleted < 9  ){
                insertIntoDB(chaptersCompleted, cnRadioBtn.getText().toString());
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(AddMenuScreen.this, "For CN valid range is 1-8", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }


    }

    private void insertIntoDB(int chaptersCompleted, String subName) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        DBHandler db = new DBHandler(this);
        db.updateSem5Table(chaptersCompleted, subName);
        Toast.makeText(AddMenuScreen.this, "Data saved successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        deselectAllRadioBtn();
        buttonView.setChecked(true);
        Toast.makeText(this, buttonView.getText().toString() + " is checked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    private void deselectAllRadioBtn() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        adbmsRadioBtn.setChecked(false);
        cnRadioBtn.setChecked(false);
        evsRadioBtn.setChecked(false);
        tcsRadioBtn.setChecked(false);
        mpRadioBtn.setChecked(false);
        weRadioBtn.setChecked(false);

    }
}
```

Comment: but there is nothing called android:name...please elaborate

Answer (score 1):

It appears to me as though your RadioGroup contains the TableRows and not the RadioButtons.  If you put the RadioButtons one level under RadioGroup that should work.

Comment: ya, but then radio button will not appear on screen how i wanted, any other solution

Comment: To my knowledge there's no other way to do this.  RadioButtons must be direct children of the group for this to work.  You could, of course, manually deselect a button when another is selected so that you make your own RadioGroup Functionality.

Comment: please any one check my onCheckChanged(..) implementation and help me to solve this problem, i have shown the code above if u need more info about what is happening or u r still confuse about what i want than please let me know.thankyou